# How to pass data in dynamic javascript inside partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
var rqs_cnt= 3

function abc (e) {
    $(e.parentNode).after(
     @Html.Partial("xyz", new ViewDataDictionary { { "Name", "company" + rqs_cnt }, { "SelectEvent", "onChange" } })');    
}
```

Getting error that `rqs_cnt` is not defined.

Comment: You cannot. `@Html.Partial()` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. `rqs_cnt` is a client javascript variable which does not even exist at that point (its not in scope)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Use ajax t call a server method that returns you partial view and update the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you